# How to enforce licensing restrictions for an SDK

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdk, linker

Here is a question I have been researching for a couple of months and need help from the community:

I am building a native SDK (.lib and .h files) on Windows which is a saleable product that my customers would buy and use it to build useful applications  (.exe files) for their end customers: a very common usecase for most SDK vendors.

I want to make a licensing scheme such that my customers are not able to share their copy of SDK with others. However they can freely distribute the end applications that they build using this SDK without needing to ask me for a license per end customer.

I have in the past written multiple licensing schemes which restrict the software at runtime to work only if a correct licensee is present (time-based, node-locked, floating). However this project requires a licensing check which happens at link time: when the developer tries to link their code to my .lib files, this lincese check should allow linker to go through only if they have a valid license.

So I am wondering if there are any linker hooks available in CL.exe (ms visual studio) which allow me to invoke a custom license checking module.

It is also important that the end user does not need a license to run the end product.

I researched all available linked options but could not spot anything useful.

Comment: I vaguely remember that IPP (intel performance primitives) has this feature, they wont let you link till you have a valid license. I'll try to snoop into it and check how it works.  Does any one already know ?

Answer (score 3):

**The prooblem:**

As far as I know, license enforcement is not a feature of the MS linker.  Even if it would, nothing would prevent your customers to use another linker who doesn't, as library files have a known definition.

The problem is intrinsic to library distribution:  in a library based SDK, you provide your customers everything they need to build nice applications without giving you account.  Nothing prevent the developpers to copy all what you provided to him to someone else.  The only think that make them rely on you is the support and guarantees you'll offer them.

**A potential solution**

You could store licensing information of your customer in the library, and inform about it. Developpers could still infridge the license, but they'll know that you'll find the leak and could sue them. This would make them more reluctant to share your work.

The difficulty is that your distribution infrastructure must be able to generate a distinct lib file for every customer.  From a practical point of view, I'd advise to work with two lib files:  one for the real library, one for the for the the licence info (aka containing a definition of global extern variable holding encrypted licence info).

On Windows you could even go one step further:  in the manifest or properties of the exe file there are several vendor specific fields suitable for controls (Copyright, Publisher, Public keu token, ...).  You could ask for this information for the generation of your license lib file, and uppon first call of a library function, you could cross check complience of these information with the licence information embedded in your library.

**Additional info**

1) Static data is not enough:

Just having the info in the library file is not enough. Your customers could simply replace your license info with dummy information, or wipe it out.  It is therefore important to encrypt data, in a way to comply with a special checksum.  Your library has then to implement a singleton control function, which first step is to control validity of license data.

2) Your customers are developpers, so they are as smart as you

What prevent them from reverse engineering your library and patch you control function ?  Or find out the checksum that you use and compute dummy licence info ?

**Conclusions**

There are certainly ways to enforce this kind of scheme, but they are expensive for you (additional developpment, complex distribution), and with enough efforts, it's possible to disable them.

On the other side, if it's too constraining for your customers, they'll simply use another library.

If I were you, I'd really think about it twice.  Happy customers of powerfull libraries tend to be loyal to their supplier.  Especially if responsive support is offered !  So why bother ?  Why not build from the start a relation of trust your customers ?